# Angularjs cannot get json data from rest API

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I need to create a todo list with laravel as backend and angularjs as frontend. I am new to this field. I am sure that my backend is returned the right json data(checked by Postman), but why angularjs is not get anything from it? I am new to this field. Please help me!

At my frontend, I have two files: todoapp.js and index.html.

todoapp.js:

```
var app = angular.module('todoapp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = "John";
    $scope.todoList = {}

    $http.get('http://localhost/201805CodeTesting/backend/public/api/todos')
        .success(function (data, status, header, config){
            $scope.todoList = data;
    });


    $scope.deleteTask = function(id) {
        $http.delete('http://localhost/201805CodeTesting/backend/public/api/todos/' + id).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.ServerResponse = id;
            });
    };

    $scope.addTask =  function() {
        var data = $.param({
            taskName: $scope.taskName,
        });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }
        $http.post('http://localhost/201805CodeTesting/backend/public/api/todos', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })
    };
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/todoapp.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Todo List App</title>
</head>
<body class="container" ng-app="todoapp" ng-controller="appCtrl"> <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>TODO List</h1>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addTask()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="taskName" ng-model="taskName" placeholder="Enter task name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in todoList">
            {{ task.id  +  ', ' + task.task + ', ' + task.status }} <br>
            <form ng-submit="deleteTask()">
                <input type="hidden" name='_method' value='DELETE'>
                <input type="submit" class = 'btn btn-danger' value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call $http like angular says(remember it returns a promise)

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).**then**(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Check the **then** method.

More samples at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

It would be helpful if you post the console error, logs or whatever you have.